# spring boot dynamic object modelling

Tags: java, oop, spring-boot

I am creating a RESTful API using spring boot. I have the requirement where I need to make a request to the resource

> /user/notification

Notification resource will accept values in bodyrequest and send the notification to users.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/notification", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public NotificationResponse sendNotification(@Valid @RequestBody NotificationRequest notificationRequest){
  // here is code where I need to build right
  // object of type text/file/link/map (please read full question below)
   notificationService.send(notificationRequest.getUsername(), object);
}
```

It accepts: **username** and data for notification. Here is **NotificationRequest** class:

```
public class NotificationRequest {

  @NotEmpty
  private String username;

  @NotEmpty
  private String type;

  private String title;

  @NotEmpty
  private String content;

  private String url;

  private String longitude;

  private String latitude;

  private String file_url;

 //getters and setters
 }
```

I have 4 types of notifications ie. text, link, map and file.  And their attributes are these.

```
text
  - type
  - title
  - content

link
  - type
  - title
  - content
  - url

map
 - type
 - title
 - longitude
 - latitude

file
 - type
 - title
 - content
 - file_url
```

I created 4 classes for these so I can create the right object, As you can see **type** and **title** are common attributes so I used inheritance.

```
public class NotificationBase {
  private String type;
  private String title;
  //getters and setters here
 }
```

And extended other 4 classes like this.

```
 public class TextNotification extends NotificationBase {
    private String content; 
   //getters and setters here
 }
```

My question is, How I create my classes so that

if someone wants to send text notification I would able to get an object of TextNotification and if someone wants to send file notification that I would able to create FileNotification object?

Note: Please note I do not want to use gJson or Jackson to create JSON objects in this case.

Please do let me know if I need to add any more information here.

Comment: Is the `type` attribute of `NotificationRequest` the actual type (text, map, etc)? If so, just instantiate according to that type. Otherwise you could have the type of notification as a query parameter on the url. You can abstract the creation process to a factory or something if you want, but that's the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jackson` annotation for subtyping. In your case, you have the field `type` that will represent what is the type of the object that you expect.

So it's better to have an abstract `NotificationRequest` class only with needed fields:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TextNotificationRequest.class, name = "text"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LinkNotificationRequest.class, name = "link")})
public abstract class NotificationRequest {

  @NotEmpty
  private String username;

  @NotEmpty
  private String type;

  private String title;

  public abstract NotificationResponse buildNotificationResponse();
}
```

And the implementation of each type that you need.

```
public class TextNotificationRequest extends NotificationRequest {
 public String content;

 public NotificationResponse buildNotificationResponse{
   return new TextNotificationResponse(content);
 }
}
```

Now you can just do something like this

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/notification", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public NotificationResponse sendNotification(@Valid @RequestBody NotificationRequest notificationRequest){
   NotificationResponse response = notificationRequest.buildNotificationResponse();
   notificationService.send(notificationRequest.getUsername(), response);
}
```

Here is some explanation. By setting these annotations your are saying to `jackson` which class to instantiate based on the value of `type` field. If `type == "text"` `jackson` will instantiate `TextNotificationRequest` and so on. And now you can use the power of polymorphism to create `NotificationResponse` and avoid `if-else` statements.

Also `jackson` allow subtyping based not only on the field value. You can read in more detailed info here [@JsonTypeInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html)